# How to know the url of Action.OpenUrl in Bot framework that was clicked?

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have a caroussel of Adaptive card where each cards contain in Action.OpenUrl . I would like to log as events in my App Insight when a url is clicked and what is the url. Is there a work around or a way to do it?

Comment: Hey, as far as i know the Action.OpenUrl is purely clientside and working similar to window.open. If what you are asking for is possible really dependsnon where you use the cards. In your own app or webchat it might be possible. In MS Teams its not.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished by using a Controller to redirect requests:

```
[Route("redirect")]
[ApiController]
public class RedirectController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult PostAsync(string url)
    {
        // TODO: Log url here
        return Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

In the Adaptive Card, templatize the url:

```
{
  "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
  "title": "Amazon",
  "url": "[baseurl]?url=https://www.amazon.com"
}
```

Then replace [baseurl] before returning the card to the client:

```
    using (var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(cardResourcePath))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var adaptiveCard = reader.ReadToEnd();

            string baseUrl = $"{_currentContext.Request.Scheme}://{_currentContext.Request.Host.Value}/redirect";

            adaptiveCard = adaptiveCard.Replace("[baseurl]", baseUrl);

            return new Attachment()
            {
                ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCard),
            };
        }
    }
```

Complete example here: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/OpenUrlRedirectBot

Comment: I hate this solution, cannot understand Microsoft... But it's the only one that seems to be working with BotFramework.

Comment: I have checked your repo and I don't understand the usage of AddHttpContextAccessor, could you please explain it?